# Removing lines based on column values read from file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I use the following code to extract lines from input_file with a certain value in the first column. The values on which the extraction of lines is based is in "one_column.txt":

```
while read file
do
awk -v col="$file" '$1==col {print $0}' input_file >> output_file
done < one_column.txt
```

My question is, how do I extract the lines where the first column does *not* match any of the values in one_column.txt? In other words, how do I extract *only* the remaining lines from input_file that don't end up in output_file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -vf` can make it:

```
 grep -vf output_file input_file
```

`grep -f` compares one file with another. `grep -v` matches the opposite.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
good
bye
$ cat b
hello
good
bye
you
all
$ grep -f a b
hello
good
bye
$ grep -vf a b ## opposite
you
all
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it me, or does this take quite some time to run when the input_file has ~12000 lines and output_file has ~4000 lines?

Comment: You are welcome! @Abdel, it might be a bit slow, yes. All in all, it is comparing two big files by buffering the first one and comparing each line.