# remove line character form csv file

Tags: linux, csv

I have 2 csv files, **file1** contain 1000 email address and **file2** contain 150 email address which are already exist in **file1**.
I wonder if there is a Linux command to remove the 150 email from **file1** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing lines based on column values read from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715230/removing-lines-based-on-column-values-read-from-file)

Comment: There is no "command" for this. You have to make a short script.

Comment: What is the exact format of the csv files? Is the format of the two files identical?

Comment: @SzG i think it's reasonable to assume they are going to be the same format, or that they would be made into the same format before comparison

Comment: some sort of sed/awk/grep. Or you could write a quick Python/Perl/Ruby script for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test this :

```
grep -vf file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv
```

it's works

Answer (score 1):

This should work, with the added benefit of providing sorted output:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```